# AngularJS simple navigating to parameterized state via URL ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to enter a `ui-router` parent or child state simply by navigating to its associated URL. I know that `ui-sref` is a proven, simple way to enter into a state via an `a` link, but just typing the URL of a state into a browser seems to always redirect me to my `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise()` statement.

For example, I would like to be able to navigate into the `page` state, via going to `example.com/#/page` in the browser. Instead, I am redirected to the `otherwise`.

JS

```
angular.module('app', [ 'ui.router', 'subapp']);
angular.module('app').config(function($urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    }).controller('appCtrl', function(){});

angular.module('subapp', ['ui.router']);
angular.module('subapp').config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.when('#/page/nothing', '/');

    $stateProvider
        .state('page', {
            url: '#/page',
            templateUrl: 'page.tpl.html'
         }) 
         .state('page.edit', {
             url: '/:myparameter',
             templateUrl: 'page-edit.tpl.html'
         });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/hello');
});
```

Index.html

```
<body ng-controller="appCtrl">
This is the index.html file<br>
<a href="#/page">Go to page state</a><br>
<a href="#/page/myparameter">Go to page child state with a parameter</a>
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

PLNKR: http://plnkr.co/edit/HQziTB2CyJrCvbgzzuJm?p=preview

ote I have a `subapp` service which is injected into the main app—but I don't think that would make a difference, as `page` state should still be a 'top-level' state injected into the index.html `<ui-view>`

How can I make it so that I can navigate to a URL (even one with a parameter) directly? The [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing) says its possible, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: In your template.html, try to replace href with ui-sref="page". Also as Leonardo's answer, change url in stateProvider from '#/page' to '/page'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, that you are almost there. There is [an updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mZYzwmT5OSLfOqsi5NuC?p=preview). But while your links could (should) be with **`#`** *(we are **not** using **`html5Mode`**)*

```
<a href="#/page">
<a href="#/page/myparameter">
<a href="#/page/11">
```

The state definition should not contain that sign:

```
.state('page', {
    // instead of this
    // url: '#/page',
    // we need this
    url: '/page',
    ...
.state('page.edit', {
    // instead of this
    // url: '#/:page',
    // we need this
    url: '/:page',
```

And then also these will work:

```
<a ui-sref="page">
<a ui-sref="page.edit({page:123})">
<a ui-sref="page.edit({page:444})">
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/mZYzwmT5OSLfOqsi5NuC?p=preview)

Comment: Question—if I were to try to enter these states from an address bar—i.e. ```www.example.com/page/123``` — is there any reason why that would not work?

Comment: It must work. Really must. Please, check it here: [#/page/12345](http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/mZYzwmT5OSLfOqsi5NuC/#/page/12345) or [#/page/444](http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/mZYzwmT5OSLfOqsi5NuC/#/page/444)

Comment: you're a damn genius!

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter URL is wrong, you cannot map URL with a fixed name and other url with a parameter cause will cause a crazy rewrite thinking this is a variable

```
        $stateProvider
          .state('page', {
                url: '#/page',
                templateUrl: 'page.tpl.html'
            } 
         ).state('page.edit', {
                url: '/:myparameter',
                templateUrl: 'page-edit.tpl.html'
        });
```

Use URL by this way:

```
        $stateProvider
          .state('page', {
                url: '/page',
                templateUrl: 'page.tpl.html'
            } 
         ).state('page.edit', {
                url: '/page/:myparameter',
                templateUrl: 'page-edit.tpl.html'
        });
```

Comment: You cannot map URL with a fixed name? Like ```/page```? I think you can, see this working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/wpl8ByShv4z9omIGvNIy?p=preview

Comment: You not understand, sorry, you cannot use fixed name in the root path and use a variable too in other route, like /page and /:myParameter this is confuse for ui-router, try to use parent paths like my example /page and /page/:myparameter